# Powerbi IF statement is only summing on the false expression, any advice how to get total sum

Tags: sql, if-statement, powerbi, aggregate, dax

[image]

The if statement is doing what I want it to, but the sum is only that of locked capital forecast. I want the total sum of the column. Any advice?

[Desired results:]
[image]
CODE:

```
Locked Capital Forecast + 30 Day Forecast = IF(AND([Locked Capital Forecast] = 0, [Gross EAC] <> 0), [Gross EAC], [Locked Capital Forecast])
```

Comment: So what result are you looking for?  It's not clear from your description

Comment: Hello david,  for the column in the far right I am trying to get the total sum of the column, so the sum should be around 20MM. Currently it is only summing the "Locked Capital Forecast (false expression), so my total sum on the bottom right is the same as the 3rd column (7MM).

Comment: Type out a table with the desired results.  Really that's not clear.

Comment: I updated the thread with the desired result. Orange is what is currently being summed and Intended result is in green, I want the sum of the entire column. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, that's a measure, not a calculated column.  And it's doing exactly what you told it to.  Measures are calculated relative to the current filter scope.

Comment: David, that is exactly what is is doing! That makes sense, is there a way around it to produce the intended result?

Comment: Might be as easy as switching to a calculated column, depending on the table design.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sum up the rows above, you need your total to iterate over each row of the appropriate granularity.

If your data is stored at the monthly granularity like the visual, then try this:

```
SUMX ( DataTable, [Locked Capital Forecast] )
```